# How to update a page saved to homescreen in iOS when you open it?

Tags: ios, webkit

A webpage can be saved to Homescreen in iOS. And made "App-capable". But when opening the page it doesn't update. It keeps same state as last you opened. Sometimes this is good, sometimes not. Is there a way to make the page reload every time the "app" is opened?

Maybe something to do with the meta-tags?
See my code. Have also link to icon and splash screen. This works fine.
To me it seems like this have changed some time ago, as other "Save-to-homepage-apps" always updated on opening earlier, but not anymore. Has Apple change this in newer versions of iOS?
I have not implemented "service worker". Do I have to?

```html
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,  user-scalable=1">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```